# parse and convert string input to int c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

INPUT: (some number, some number)
Example: (12,2345235)
How would I parse this input, stored as a string, and convert it to integers?

Is it possible to create a string from the '(' to the ','

Then the other number would begin where the ',' and end ')'

This way no matter how large the input is, it will be stored.

Additionally, if the input is: badcharacters(12,324)badcharacters
would you still be able to retrieve the 12 and 324 and store them as integers, so long as the correct input is somewhere inside the string?

Comment: You could see if `sscanf` does the job: e.g., `if (sscanf(szInput, "(%d,%d)", &int1, &int2) == 2) /* success */ else /* failure */;`.  That's assuming `szInput` stores the input; if the input is via stdin, then just use `scanf`.

Comment: Note: The input is already stored as a string.

Comment: Then `sscanf` is the way to go.  I suggest checking its return value as above to make sure both integers were successfully parsed -- something often neglected, but useful.

Comment: You have significantly changed the question. This is not fair. Moreover, you are not putting any effort into writing any code yourself.

Comment: The question hasn't changed, I've added a secondary condition however.

Comment: You changed the question that requires a different solution than the original, especially when people already gave answers voiding their work and answers to help you, this is not fair in my book. Either way, you cannot just give the tasks one after another without writing any code yourself.

Comment: Removing my edit doesn't change the fact that your answer isn't helpful/applicable.

Comment: Good luck with this approach on the site. I personally already lost the motivation to help. Who knows what else you will still put into the question even if one helps. In any case, you will need to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry that you didn't understand the question.

Comment: No one has understood your question, apparently. Please read the help center entry. It is essential to ask good questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the scanf family for instance like this if the string comes from file:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs ("test.txt", ifstream::in);
    char buf[256];
    int i1, i2;
    while (ifs.getline(buf, 256)) {
        sscanf(buf, "(%i,%i)", &i1, &i2);
        cout << i1 << " " << i2 << endl;
    }

    ifs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
12 2345235
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const int SIZE=100;
char input[SIZE]

// Read the input into the string.
fgets(input, SIZE-1, stdin);

// Extract the integers out of it.
int n1;
int n2;
sscanf(input, "(%d,%d)", &n1, &n2);
```